# do we need to initialize multiple templates for multiple functions in c++?

Tags: c++, function, templates

If you didnt understand the question then I will try to explain it here . I want to make a couple of functions that I need to be able to run in different datatypes so I was wandering if I need to make seperate templates for seperate functions?

Comment: I still don't understand the quesiton. Please add your code to the question

Comment: The answer is probably "yes". An example of what you're trying to do (with some code) would help.

Comment: Each function should must have its own set of templates if it is not a class member function. But once created, the function will fit any type that is suitable for operations done in the functions. You might need to instantiate templates, only only if you export them from shared objects or dynamic linked libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a function usable with multiple datatypes you can use Templates which make it very easy to call a function with different datatypes.

```
template<typename T>
void Print(T text)
{ 
   std::cout << text << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to add another function that returns a different result you need to create a new function as well as a new template. **Important** the `template<typename YourName>` must be defined over each function that uses typenames

```
template<typename T>
void PrintDifferent(T text)
{ 
   std::cout << text << "This function is totally different" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe unfortunate examples, type of `T+T` (and `T-T`) is not necessarily `T`. Take `uint8_t` + `uint8_t` for example.

Comment: But anyway, I don't know if this is the answer to the original question, since it is a bit vague.

Comment: @MikaelH Thanks for the feedback which example would you use. As for the question I'm not that sure myself but tried to answer it nevertheless.

Comment: Maybe something as simple as `template<typename T>void print(T t) { std::cout << t << "\n"; }`. But for demonstration purposes it should be fine what you already have, but perhaps note that they are not correct.

Comment: I will thanks for the addition I'm always open to constructive criticism. I'm new to answering on Stack Overflow as well as relatively new to C++.